# ert and elint: Use (eval-when-compile (ert-deftest ....))?

Tags: ert

I'm trying `elint` for the first time, because I just learned that it reports things that bytecode compiling doesn't.

Mainly it is showing me a few missing `require`s, which I'm adding.

Only a `tests.el` is giving many warnings and errors. Distilled example:

```
(require 'ert)
(ert-deftest my/test ()
  (should t))
```

`elint-current-buffer` reports:

```
In top level expression:
tests.el:2:Warning: Reference to unbound symbol: my/test
tests.el:2:Error: Call to undefined function: should
```

I figured it might have something to do with macro evaluation. And indeed this makes `elint` happy:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (ert-deftest my/test ()
    (should t)))
```

However. I've never seen anyone do this. (Not that I've read all Elisp ever written. But I've looked at a fair amount, and even tried a quick GitHub search. I also didn't see any discussion of this in `ert` or `elint` docs/comments.)

Practically speaking, should I bother to do this?

(I realize "the value of linting" is probably an opinion-based question, which is no good. That's not my intent. I'm looking for practical advice from experienced Elisp programmers -- what sort of problems will I have from either using or not using `eval-when-compile` here?)

Comment: Does your original code also have an extra parenthesis in the `require` line? Provided it's not, my guess would be that lint has a "strange" way of discovering what macros are available and at what time. What would happen if instead of defining the test at compile time you instead required `ert` at compile time?

Comment: 1. Sorry, `(require 'ert))` was a copy-pasta typo. 2. Yes, `(eval-when-compile (require 'ert))` seems sufficient; I can remove the `eval-when-compile` wrapper from all the `ert-deftest` forms.